# VBA formula referencing a changing sheet name

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I am new to VBA and am trying to create a code that uses the formula which references a sheet. However, the sheet name changes every month. What functions should I be using to reference the sheet?

I have thought of creating a simple macro to rename the sheet in question as "Raw data" to be easily referenced in the formula code but I would wish to avoid doing so. This is the code so far:

```
Range("J2").Formula = "=SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH(Checklist!R2C1:R6C1,WorkSheets(1)!RC[-1])))>0"
```

Worksheets(1) is the constantly changing sheet name that I wish to reference in the code. I thought of using Worksheets(1) to reference the left most worksheet since that does not require the sheet's name. J2 is the cell in the sheet which constantly changes name.

Comment: What is the name of the worksheet containing this formula, the one with `Range("J2")`? Specify it. Instead of `,WorkSheets(1)!` use `,'" & ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Name & "'!`.

Comment: oops forgot to mention that. yes J2 is the cell of the constantly changing worksheet name containing the formula. I have 3 sheets currently, Raw Data (the one that changes name), Checklist, Summary. J2 is in the Raw Data sheet. 
the code now references the sheet in the hidden macro workbook. is there any way to reference it to the Raw Data sheet workbook?

Answer (score 0):

I have modified the code to `,'" & ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Name & "'!` and it is working as intended now. Thanks for the help!!